# You tube API live Stream Schedule time zone

Tags: php, youtube-api

I am using the following time format in You tube API to schedule Live Streaming.

```
"2015-08-28T00:00:00.000Z"

 $broadcastSnippet->setScheduledStartTime('2015-08-28T00:00:00.000Z');
  $broadcastSnippet->setScheduledEndTime('2015-08-29T00:00:00.000Z');
```

After the scheduling the live stream.It's created in `GMT-7` timezone.i need to create the live stream in `GMT+5:30`.

How can i schedule live stream in `GMT+5:30`.

Please suggest

Comment: So, you just need to change timezone. See info about formats https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 and try setup your timezone as you need.

Comment: Can you please give one example for setting indian time zone?